# How to write fluent bit input logs to localhost syslog server

Tags: docker, fluentd, syslog, rsyslog, fluent-bit

I'm working on collecting logs from docker containerized application. I'm able to bring the logs to stdout output plugin but when I am trying syslog output plugin then it is not writing on syslog server.
Below is the configuration file.

```
[SERVICE]
    Parsers_File        /etc/td-agent-bit/parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name                forward

[Output]
    name                syslog
    match               *
    host                127.0.0.1
    port                514
    mode                udp
    syslog_format       rfc5424
    syslog_hostname_key hostname
    syslog_appname_key  appname
    syslog_procid_key   procid
    syslog_message_key  log
```

The logging property for container application is set to

```
logging:
  driver: fluentd
  options:
    fluentd-address: localhost:24224
    tag: logs
```

After running the fluent bit `/opt/td-agent-bit/bin/td-agent-bit -c fluent.conf`

```
[2021/09/20 08:47:16] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '8481-1632152835.361162854.flb', retry in 7 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
[2021/09/20 08:47:23] [ warn] [engine] chunk '8481-1632152835.361162854.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=syslog.0
[2021/09/20 08:47:26] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '8481-1632152845.361118393.flb', retry in 6 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
[2021/09/20 08:47:32] [ warn] [engine] chunk '8481-1632152845.361118393.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=syslog.0
[2021/09/20 08:47:36] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '8481-1632152855.361556013.flb', retry in 8 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
```

Can anyone tell what is going wrong here?

Even for simple cpu input plugin syslog does not work. like

```
/opt/td-agent-bit/bin/td-agent-bit -i cpu -o syslog
```

output

```
[2021/09/20 08:53:43] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.2.1
[2021/09/20 08:53:43] [ info] [output:syslog:syslog.0] setup done for 127.0.0.1:514
[2021/09/20 08:53:43] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[2021/09/20 08:53:48] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '8765-1632153224.515974981.flb', retry in 10 seconds: task_id=0, input=cpu.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
[2021/09/20 08:53:53] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '8765-1632153228.516869744.flb', retry in 6 seconds: task_id=1, input=cpu.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
[2021/09/20 08:53:58] [ warn] [engine] chunk '8765-1632153224.515974981.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=0, input=cpu.0 > output=syslog.0
```

Comment: how did you managed to do it eventually?

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar issue, happening because fluentbit pod itself is 127.0.0.1. i created another rsyslog pod and used its IP to get logs from fluentbit.
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/rsyslog/rsyslog